# "checkedbycsshelper=true"

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

In building my responsive website I have come across a bug that appears only in IE8, and I cannot figure out why. I use a cross browser testing service (as I build on a Mac) and on my portfolio page - http://www.weblinedesign.com.au/portfolio in firebug, I notice on nearly every line, there is added code "**checkedbycsshelper=true**". It's preventing my images from loading as the  tags wrapping the image tags have been disabled - assumed by this line of code.

It doesn't happen in any other browser, only IE8 and all my attempts at searching Google have come up null. There are literally no references anywhere in Google to "**checkedbycsshelper**".

Comment: I also face the same issue, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being added by this script:

http://www.weblinedesign.com.au/wp-content/themes/wd/js/css3-mediaqueries.js

I'm not sure why, but I'd check around for newer versions of that script, and/or other reports of issues with that script on IE8.

Comment: Thank you very much. My way round it for now was doing a conditional run in IE7 compatibility mode if browser = IE8.

Answer (score 1):

A bug report has been opened on the developer's Google Code repo, but not yet resolved.
(http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/issues/detail?id=8)