# MeanMenu not working in IE. what does checkedbycsshelper = true mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

MeanMenu is not working properly in IE. It is working in Chrome and Mozilla. On IE I am getting checkedbycsshelper = "true" what does this mean? The submenu is not appearing onclick.

Below is the site link.

http://www.travcoholidays.com/

Answer (score 1):

This has been covered in a previous question.

Here i hope this helps:

["checkedbycsshelper=true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087456/checkedbycsshelper-true)

The user resolved their issue by doing a conditional run in IE7 compatibility mode if browser = IE8. It might be a similar resolution for you.

Comment: I have tried but it is not working for me. I have gone through all the posts. Bottom divs can be problem for not appearing the submenu?